# Why do my Twitter mentions dissapear?

Tags: twitter

It happened to me twice already. I had quite a few twitter mentions but all of a sudden they completely disappear and never come back?

Does Twitter delete old records in their database or something? Is it possible to get them back somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this issue?

http://support.twitter.com/groups/32-something-s-not-working/topics/119-tweet-dm-problems/articles/76078-i-m-missing-mentions-and-replies-known-issue

Comment: Looks like it is... Thanks. I hope they'll resolve this issue ASAP.